# can't disable css animation even after commenting out/deleting

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

I've commented out/deleted the following code for the header-bg's zoom animation, but it's still running on my site and appears in console:

```
/*
@keyframes bg-zoom {
   0% {
        transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.3);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
}
*/
.home-header-wrapper-bg {
    content: "";
    background: #fff url("...") center center no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
/*
    animation: bg-zoom 30s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: bg-zoom 30s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
*/
}
```

I've also cleared my cache. Demo: [here](http://www.brettchien.com)

Comment: Try removing it altogether and test again so we know that it's not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML file not css file, find this code and remove it

```
var x;
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            x = $(window).scrollTop();
            $('.home-header-wrapper-bg').css('background-size', 100 + parseInt(x / 1, 0) + '% ');
});
```

Also remove this one too:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
            $(".home-header-container").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's probably some javascript that is causing that. When I inspect the "home-header-wrapper-bg" and begin scrolling, it starts to change the opacity and background-size inline and not in a stylesheet.